# How to set flags when re-use QgsFeatureRequest object

Tags: flag, qgsfeaturerequest

I have a standalone PyQGis application that is working fine. When I query a vector layer via QgsFeatureRequest class, I would like to instantiate one object and reuse it. But I am not sure how to set- and unset- some flags. For example,

```
request = QgsFeatureRequest()    
expr = QgsExpression(expr_text)
request.setFilterExpression(expr_text)
if no_geometry:
   request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
else:
   # does the following line undo the above 'NoGeometry' setting?
   request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoFlags)

if subset_attribute:
   request.setSubsetOfAttributes([ind])
else:
   # here, what should I do to undo the above 'setSubsetOfAttributes'???
```

I guess the bigger question is whether I should keep creating new implicit QgsFeatureRequest objects when query or should I keep one instance and change its flags as above, which way is better?